# Скролл длинной таблицы, но с элементами, выступающими за границы скролла

Tags: html, css, table, scrollbar, overflow

Требуется обеспечить скролл длинной таблицы полосами прокрутки,
но с возможностью внутренних элементов выходить за рамки скролла.

[image: Описание того, что требуется, скрин.]

[Пример верстки](https://codepen.io/arykov/pen/abqbvEL)

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.table {
  width: 3000px;
}
... см.пример
```

Comment: А зачем они тогда в скролле лежат, если им нужно быть поверх остального?

Comment: таблица должна помещаться в ширину. а менюшка у ячеек всплывает вниз. но задавая любой overflow автоматически включается вся обрезка и по X и по Y.

Comment: У Вас в таком случае можно только при клике на что-то рисовать отдельный блок, который подстраивается под позицию. Исходя из Вашей концепции, Вы можете попробовать что-то сделать из ответов здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013066. Но с элементами в такой вложенности вряд ли получится перебить overflow.

Comment: тебе нужно где-то отдельно делать выпадающие ячейки и накладывать их абсолютом поверх таблицы.

Comment: В итоге сделал меню через всплывающее окно. Каждое меню - отдельно от таблицы.